# C# How to pass a Boolean variable as a parameter - the actual variable not only the value

Tags: c#, parameters, boolean

I am trying to make a function which allows to have a Boolean as a parameter and change the value of that Boolean in the function.
Here is code below:

It seems to not change the value of the original `bool` variable passed in the parameter.

```
void myToggleFunction(bool pBool)

    {
        if (!pBool)
        {
            pBool = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pBool = false;
        }
    }
```

I have a `bool`:

```
public bool myBool = false;
```

I call the function as:

```
myToggleFunction(myBool);
```

When I create a breakpoint I see it's changing the value of `pBool` but is not changing the value of the `bool` I passed in the parameter.

Comment: What you're referring to is often called "passing by reference".  If and how you accomplish this depends entirely on the language being used.

Comment: One easy, somewhat more language-independent method is to return a value instead of passing by reference: `bool toggle(bool in) { return !in; }`, which you'd call like: `myBool = toggle(myBool);`. This still isn't universal, of course, but it works for a fair number of C-like languages. The syntax for passing by reference varies quite a bit more.

Comment: Thank you David i updated question. I am using c#.. so you are saying i should pass a reference.. for example:
void myToggleFunction(ref bool pBool);

and call the function by:
myToggleFunction(ref myBool); 

i did this and it worked, thank you!

Comment: If your question is actually about specific language - please [edit] the post to add a tag. Obviously there are plenty of questions on how by ref/by value works in all sorts of languages - make sure to clarify why none of the existing questions in the language you are interested in (looks like C# based on your comment) did not help with understanding the problem.

Comment: Why down vote the question? I accidentally didn't write c# in the Title but i edited 1 minute after..  Please at least give a reason so I can improve instead of just downvoting and going away

Comment: @ Alexei The Title had c# in it and now i added it as a tag, thanks. If you downvoted.. is this why you downvoted because you didnt see C# in the tag?

Answer (score -1):

The Answer (thanks to David) is to use a 'reference':

```
void myToggleFunction(ref bool pBool)
{
    if (!pBool)
    {
        pBool = true;
    }
    else
    {
        pBool = false;
    }
}
```

and when calling the function is needed to pass as reference:

```
myToggleFuntion(ref myBool);
```